# Indention in Spherical Shape

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I am super (SUPER) new to blender. I used it for a while in 2017 or 18, but only re-picked it up about a week ago. I've been trying to make an indention in a spherical (not perfectly circle,) object that is still the same shape as the spherical-like object. The intentions would be circles as well as U shapes. I have tried beveling a cylinder through it for the circle, but that makes the indention uneven, one side being much deeper than the other.

As reference, I found this 3D model someone else made that has created the same effect I'm trying to create, which I've attached to this forum post. Thank you so much for your time!
[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. make sure you have the looptools add-on enabled (comes with Blender, it is a free add-on)

1b) make sure your base geometry has quad faces so that the geometry still looks good if we add subdivision surface modifier

2. in edit mode: select one vertex where the center of your circular hole should be
3. press ctrl-b (bevel) then v (vertex bevel)
4. choose 2 segments
5. right click -> meshtools -> circle
6. select the vertices as in the gif and press J to connect them - by this you will guarantee a smooth surface later on
7. now press I to insert a support edge loop, move mouse only a little bit

[image]

8. now press E to insert a support edge loop ....

[image]

9. E -> move mouse now for depth

[image]

10. E -> support loop

[image]

11. I -> support loop

[image]

12. add subdivision modifier

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

video tutorial: https://youtu.be/3KR7EEbTxvw